# Hide navigation bar after page refresh in Midori

Tags: midori

I've set up my Raspberry in that way, that it opens up Midori on start up.
Midori then loads a html page in full screen mode. Everything works as expected.

But I also specified a refresh interval with the parameter `-i 3600`. The problem occurs after the first refresh of the page because after that refresh is the navigation bar shown.

Someone had the same problem here: [Raspberry Pi Forum](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=91&t=87719).

His solution was to switch from Midori to Minimal Kiosk Browser (kweb). But I don't want to do this.

So is there a way to hide the navigation bar after a refresh?

Regards, winklerrr

Comment: no one seems to have created a bug for that, so it is unlikely to get fixed unless you can fix it yourself, it is open source. https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori

Comment: @rob So should I create a bug for that? Because I don't think, that I can fix it by myself.

Comment: yes, that is what I meant to say.

Comment: So here is the bug:
https://bugs.launchpad.net/midori/+bug/1377831
I added it right away when you mentioned it, but I forgot to add the link here. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 2):

I use xdotool to solve the problem.

I created a bash loop every 60 seconds. This script is launched with autostart lxsession

```
#!/bin/bash

while true
do
    WID=`xdotool search --name "TITLE OF PAGE IN MIDORI" | head-1`
    xdotool windowfocus --sync $WID 
    xdotool click 1
    sleep 60
done
```

TrinitA

Comment: I edited your post mostly for grammar (and indenting the code) but also corrected some errors: 1) There is no point in using a second shebang, `#!/bin/bash`, anywhere inside a bash script.  It will just be ignored as a comment (you might as well make it `#!/Hey/whatever`). 2) A `do` loop should be closed with `done`.   You can see the previous version of your answer by clicking the "edited" link above my lil' bear.

Comment: Hi, no problem. i'm a french and a newbie here. I will try to do best:). Thank You.